# Comparing two strings that return the equivalent substring in c++

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

I have a function subString that takes in two strings. I loop through my first string to generate substrings of at least size >= 4. I want to find a substring that exists in my second string. For example:

**string1**: "ABCDE"   **string2**: "XY**BCDE**FGH"

substrings of string1 include: **"ABCD"**, **"ABCDE"**, **"BCDE"**

So, I want to compare the substrings generated to string2 and return **"BCDE"**

I'm confused on how to compare the two strings. I looked through the STL string library (https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), but I got stuck trying to find the right method for this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

void subString(string s1, string s2){
    int n = 4;
    int strLength = s1.length();
    string firstString;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= strLength - i; j++){
            if (s1.substr(i,j).length() >= n){
                firstString = s1.substr(i,j);
                cout << firstString << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s1;
    string s2;
    
    cin >> s1;
    cin >> s2;
    subString(s1, s2);
}
```

Comment: [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) can be used to find a substring within a string, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

1. Return a vector of substrings.
2. Then loop through the vector and search in s2 string using find
   method.

See below code sample.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> subString(string s1, string s2){
    int n = 4;
    int strLength = s1.length();
    string firstString;
    vector<string> substrings;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= strLength - i; j++){
            if (s1.substr(i,j).length() >= n){
                firstString = s1.substr(i,j);
                substrings.push_back(firstString);
            }
        }
    }
    return substrings;
}

int main()
{
    string s1 = "ABCDE";
    string s2 = "XYBCDEFGH";

    for (auto value : subString(s1, s2))
    {
        if (s2.find(value) != string::npos)
            cout << "found " << value << endl;
    }
}
```

**Output of this code**

```
found BCDE
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why we need to use vectors to accomplish this?

Comment: Vector was the first thing that came to my mind for this problem. There could be other ways to do this also